# fish shell : capture multi-line output to a variable with piping or read

Tags: fish

if you

```
curl https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore/api/python
```

you see the file as expected, with newlines. But if I

```
set response (curl https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore/api/python)
echo $response
```

in fish the newlines are gone. I've looked at fish `read` but

```
url $gitignoreurlbase/python | read response # I have also tried read -d 'blah'
echo $response
```

just shows a blank.

How do I capture the multi-line output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace `set var (command)` with `set var (command | string split0)`

Explanation:

command substition splits on newlines by default. The $response variable is a **list of lines** of the output. This is [documented](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#command-substitution)

```
$ set var (seq 10)
$ set --show var
$var: not set in local scope
$var: set in global scope, unexported, with 10 elements
$var[1]: length=1 value=|1|
$var[2]: length=1 value=|2|
$var[3]: length=1 value=|3|
$var[4]: length=1 value=|4|
$var[5]: length=1 value=|5|
$var[6]: length=1 value=|6|
$var[7]: length=1 value=|7|
$var[8]: length=1 value=|8|
$var[9]: length=1 value=|9|
$var[10]: length=2 value=|10|
$var: not set in universal scope
```

Fortunately so is the remedy

```
$ set var (seq 10 | string split0)
$ set -S var
$var: not set in local scope
$var: set in global scope, unexported, with 1 elements
$var[1]: length=21 value=|1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10\n|
$var: not set in universal scope

# OR
$ set oldIFS $IFS
$ set --erase IFS
$ set var (seq 10)
$ set -S var
$var: not set in local scope
$var: set in global scope, unexported, with 1 elements
$var[1]: length=20 value=|1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10|
$var: not set in universal scope
$ set IFS $oldIFS
```

Note the difference with the `string split0` keeping the trailing newline.

If you're OK with $response being a list of lines, but you just want to display it properly:

```
printf "%s\n" $response

# or, with just a literal newline as the join string
string join "
" $respose
```

Comment: My apologies I didn't RTFM carefullly enough. The very short version of your answer would be “pipe through `string split0` before capturing” ?

Comment: A small addition - if you want to specify a variable inline, not through another command, use echo with '-e' option:   `set var (echo -e "line1\nline2" | string split0)`